# ESP32 Max number of GPIOs pullup

Tags: esp32

Is there a limit on the number of GPIO that can be set to INPUT_PULLUP at the same time?

My project is based on an ESP32 Devkit board. I've enabled the internal pullup resistor on 7-8 GPIOs. Each one is connected to ground via a switch. Wires are 5-10m long:

```
gpio
  |
switch
  |
 Gnd
```

Most GPIOs are ok. But a few of them (gpio5,16,17) does not delivers 3.3V. I get values like 2.1V which is not enough to read a HIGH state on the gpio.

The board is powered via the USB port. It also powers a 8 relays board.

Thanks.

Comment: You are probably confusing something else.  Regardless an internal.pullup is going to be too weak for a long wire run, long runs traditionally call for firmer drive (lower vale resistor) to limit suspectibility to induced noise, and your relays suggest the project may have or be connected to its own sources of such.  You may want more electrically robust line receivers as well.

Comment: Have you checked if those pins have something else connected already, e.g. some internal functions, like strap resistors to set correct boot mode etc?

Comment: I've chosen the pins based on https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-pinout-reference-gpios/ . It says Gpio16&17 are for UART2 Rx Tx, but I don't use uart2, at least not to my knowledge (I flashed the board with µpython firmware).

Comment: @Chris. You suggest I should try with a low value external resistor (1K ?) and disable the internal pullup? One odd thing is even when I remove the wires, I still measure 2.1V on the faulty gpio.